# Why is Winforms Designer file is full of controls that are never added to Form's ControlCollection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

## Scenario

I'm working on a refactor of a massive Winforms form, and the `.Designer.vb` file is full of control that are declared, but never actually added to the form's `ControlCollection` via `Me.Controls.Add`.

## What I've tried

I've tried adding a control to the form through the designed and letting VS regenerate the designer file, but the orphans are still rendered.

## Example

The label is declared and created

```
Friend WithEvents Label82 As System.Windows.Forms.Label

'Label82
'
Me.Label82.AutoSize = True
Me.Label82.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 245)
Me.Label82.Name = "Label82"
Me.Label82.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(61, 13)
Me.Label82.TabIndex = 141
Me.Label82.Text = "People"
Me.Label82 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
```

but then `Label82` is missing from the block of code where the controls are added to the Form's ControlCollection

```
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label80)
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label81)
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label83)
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label84)
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label85)
```

There are countless other controls in the same created-but-never-added state.

## Questions

1. How did this happen ?

   1. I suspect it's a result of controls being copy-pasted, and them deleted. They seem to be duplicates of each-other.
2. Is there anyway I can easily discover and delete all the un-added controls en masse ?
3. Do I really need to remove the controls? Could they impacting performance at all?

   1. The only real detriment is they're making refactor difficult because I can't easily tell which ones are *real* controls.

Comment: Are you sure they are not added to a panel within the form?

Comment: Right-Click on Label82 and select "Find All References".  This will open the Find Symbol Window.  The you can inspect the entries to see if it is ever added to a control collection.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, I am sure the controls are not added to any other control's ControlCollection.

Comment: @TnTinMn Find All References will work, but I've hundreds of these orphans to deal with. I'm looking for something faster.